# How to take multiline string input seperated by enter("\n") and ends with double enter ("\n\n) in java?

Tags: java

How to take multiline strings input (separated by enter (\n) and ends with (\n\n)) from console.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split("\\n");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
        }
```

Example:- 
my name is xyz
i am from india
thats it
\n
\n
(done after double enter)

output :
my name is xyz
i am from india
thats it

Comment: Please first post you attempts.

Comment: Read lines until you read an empty line, then join the lines. with `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the delimiter to that object...

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter("\n\n");
```

Comment: I am not able to take multiline String input from console sperates by enter (\n). please help

Answer (score 0):

use Delimiter 
eg: in.useDelimiter("\n\n");
 hope this works